# Heroku issue: NameError (uninitialized constant Cartographer::Gmap):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Just wondering if anyone can please help me with a heroku issue (seems so many of these!)... I am working with cartographer on my local server and have a great little map that loads up with user profile pages... However, I can't seem to get the same thing working on Heroku due to the above error message. I initially installed cartographer using `git clone git://github.com/parolkar/cartographer.git vendor/plugins/cartographer` and this worked fine on my local server.. then I tried installing the cartographer gem through gemfile, and re-deploying, but this didn't change the error.

Anyone have a clue on this issue? Thanks!

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0.rc2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'pg'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'cartographer'
gem 'gon'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'mocha'

group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
    gem 'nifty-generators'
end  

group :production do
  # gems specifically for Heroku go here
  # gem 'therubyracer-heroku'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'libnotify'
    gem 'webrat'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

gem "mocha", :group => :test
```

Comment: Which version of Rails you use ? 2 or 3 ? Have you a Gemfile ?

Comment: Have you commit the clone of cartographer ? or link by git-submodule ?

Comment: Shingara, I tried doing the clone first, and this worked on my local server... but then failed on heroku... so next I tried adding the gem to my gemfile.. still failed.

Comment: Sorry my gemfile needs to be cleaned up =(

Comment: rails 3.2.2 is out. Prefer this version instead of RC version. Quick note too. Plugin system are delete in Rails 4 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gem and the plugin is not the same project, but 2 differents :

- Gem => https://github.com/erikh/cartographer/
- Plugin => https://github.com/parolkar/cartographer

If you want use the gem add it only on your Gemfile

If you want use the plugin you need add it by git-submodule

```
rm -rf vendor/plugins/cartographer
git submodule add git://github.com/parolkar/cartographer.git vendor/plugins/cartographer
git submodule init
git commit -m 'add cartographer like submodule'
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks Shingara. Banging my head against the wall on that one!